# Button action inside a collection view cell in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

In my collection view 6 cells are there. every cell has a button. if i will tap on any of the button, then the image of button will be changed to tick mark image and all other cell button will be changed to untick mark image.Please any one help me. I have added the code and the image here.

In this image a tableview is there and inside the tableview cell collectionview is there.

[image]

My code is:-

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InsuranceCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? InsuranceCollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        cell.selectionButton.tag = indexPath.row
        let insuranceTypeAtIndex = insuranceTypeArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.insuranceTypeLabel.text = insuranceTypeAtIndex
        cell.selectionButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }


   @objc func selectButtonAction(sender: UIButton){
        let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        let cell = insuranceTypeCollectionView.cellForItem(at: index) as? InsuranceCollectionViewCell
     
        
        if cell?.selectionButton.currentImage == UIImage(named: "untick"){
            cell?.selectionButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "tick"), for: .normal)
            print(cell?.insuranceTypeLabel.text)
        }
        else{
            cell?.selectionButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "untick"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a button in the collection view. You should use here the delegate method func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

In this delegate you can toggle the checkmark when clicked by the user.

The collection view cell should then be a label and a view that simulates a checkmark box.

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Comment: Curious since I'm in a similar situation, what is the issue with using a button in a collection view? From what I understand, selection is not the same as click or spacebar.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation pattern for getting state of selected button.

First, create a protocol for collection view cell class (call the delegate method for selected button state after changing the visuals)

Then, conform the table view cell class with that protocol, and set the delegate to self for table view cell class in cell for item at method of collection view

Then, if you want to keep track of selected collection view item here in this table view cell class then keep a variable here, and in the delegate method set that variable

If you want to get the data at the class where table view is implemented, do the same for table view (create protocol for table view cell class, and conform the class to it where table view implementation is made).